# Add a class to an HTML element on:click in Svelte

Tags: javascript, svelte

How to add a class on click to Svelte inline?

```
<li on:click = {() => { this.classList.add('active'); }}>First</li>
```

The above is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `this` is not bound in arrow functions.
2. You are not supposed to do that anyway.
   Use the `class` attribute with dynamic values or [`class:active={...}`](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-element-directives-class-name). The latter should ensure that the scoped styling still works properly without using [`:global()`](https://svelte.dev/docs#component-format-style).

(You are also not supposed to add click handlers on elements that are not buttons, it's inaccessible.)

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way you can do it:

```html
<script>
  let clicked = false;
</script>
<li on:click|once={() => { clicked = true; }} class:active={ clicked }>First</li>
<style>
  li.active { color: red; }
</style>
```

The `class:` directive evaluates an expression and sets that class if true.

If the element is intended to be clicked just once, you can add the `once` modifier so it doesn't listen to subsequent click events.